Clear smart_date time input values after validation error
I have a smart_date field. During creation of a content with the smart_date field, when an error occurs on the time/date such as incorrect format, etc.. I want the values to be cleared.
Here is what I came up with so far.. I added a custom validation. When a form detects any error related to the smart_date field, then I must set the values to NULL.
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'node_basic_page_form':
    case 'node_basic_page_edit_form':
      $form['#validate'][] = '_my_module_custom_form_validation';
      break;
  }
}

function _my_module_custom_form_validation(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $errors = $form_state->getErrors();
  $prefix = "field_smartdate";
  $isset = false;
  
  // Detect if any errors related to field_smartdate.
  foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, $prefix) === 0) {
      $isset = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if ($form_state->hasAnyErrors() && $isset) {
    $form_state->setValue('field_smartdate', NULL);
    $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
  }
}

I need this

to display like this

